# Me faltan 2 parámetros en mi Php

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas tengo una duda no se que parámetros me podrían faltar dice una advertencia que falta 1 en el query y en el array.
Les dejo el código

```
<head>
    <title>
        Inicio de sesión
    </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#303030">
<body text="#E5E5E5">
<font face="tahoma">
<font size = "2">
<body link = "#E5E5E5" vlink="E0E0E0">
<p align="center">
<STRONG>Respuesta a su identificacion</STRONG>
<br>
<br>

<?
echo "string";
$host = "mysql.hostinger.mx";
$user = "u669511486_pablo";
$password = "123456";
$db ="u669511486_regis";
$conexion = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.mx","u669511486_pablo","123456");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,"u669511486_regis");
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT nombre FROM  usuarios WHERE usuario LIKE ´$usuario´ and contraseña LIKE '$cont´",$conexion);
$dato = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$cambia = $dato["nombre"];

echo "<hr size = 10 color = ffffff width = 100% align = left>";
if ($dato == "") {

    echo "Los datos no son correctos, <a href=http://portalcbtis253.esy.es/registro.php>Volver";
    # code...
} else {
    echo "<STRONG> Bienvenido a nuestro portal del cbtis 253
    $cambia </STRONG>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Los datos son lo más precioso de cualquier programa, si no aprendes a manejarlos bien te sucederán pequeños problemas como estos y aún peores. Por ejemplo tu código tiene varios errores o faltas de optimización, uno de ellos es que el nombre de la BD lo puedes pasar en la 1ª llamada `mysqli_connect()`. Luego tu consulta tiene errores de sintaxis, usas comillas simples y la comilla de escape de MySQL indistintamente. Y otras cosas, pero **lo peor** es que tu consulta es vulnerable a la **Inyección SQL**. Sería bueno que te informes un poco sobre eso antes de continuar.

Answer (score 1):

en `mysqli_connect` te falta la base de datos
en `mysqli_query` los parámetros están invertidos
¿si ya definiste tus variables por que los vuelves a poner hardcode?

un ejemplo minimo de la conexión con mysqli seria el siguiente:

```
$host = "mysql.hostinger.mx";
$user = "u669511486_pablo";
$password = "123456";
$db ="u669511486_regis";
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM  usuarios WHERE usuario ='".$usuario."' and contraseña = '".$cont."'";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$cambia = $fila["nombre"];
```

sin embargo hacerlo de esta manera no es recomendado por razones de seguridad, si vas a implementarlo en entorno de producción deberías tener las siguientes precauciones:

- poner tus credenciales en un lugar seguro:
  tus datos de acceso deberías guardarlas en un directorio no accesible para los usuarios, procura que el host se conecte directamente al localhost y que el usuario solo tenga acceso localmente en mysql el usuario debería tener ademas los permisos mínimos necesarios.

te quedaría un archivo así:

```
define("HOST", "localhost");     // El alojamiento al que deseas conectarte
define("USER", "u669511486_pablo");    // El nombre de usuario de la base de datos
define("PASSWORD", "123456");    // La contraseña de la base de datos
define("DATABASE", "u669511486_regis");
```

crear un adaptador para la conexión también es una buena practica.

```
include_once 'credenciales.php';  // el archivo con tus credenciales

function getmysqli() {
    static $mysqli = null;
    if (is_null($mysqli)) {
        $mysqli = new MySQLi(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
```

- para evitar la inyección SQL realiza peticiones preparadas:

por ejemplo:

```
  include_once '../includes/db_connect.php'; // el adaptador

$mysqli=getmysqli();
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM  usuarios WHERE usuario =? and contraseña = ?)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $usuario,$cont);  
        $stmt->execute();  
}
```

Comment: No es bueno dar soluciones al OP sobre un código **peligroso**. Por ejemplo este código es presa fácil de la [**Inyección SQL**](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php). Si alguien escribe esto en el input que recoge el password: `123456; DELETE FROM usuario;`  supongo que imaginas lo que pasaría. Me extraña que no lo menciones en tu respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano por la forma en que fue preguntado parece que el OP esta aprendiendo a usar PHP y Mysql,y ya que en la propia pagina de documentación de PHP el ejemplo mínimo es muy similar a la solución que di,  no me parecieron necesarias las advertencias de seguridad, pero modifico mi solución con las advertencias adecuadas.Gracias.

Comment: El que se esté comenzando no impide que al responder a una duda se den al mismo tiempo recomendaciones de buenas prácticas , mucho más si se trata de algo tan importante como la seguridad de los datos. Saludos.