# Llenar select con datos de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estoy tratando de llenar un `select` con los datos de una tabla llamada `municipios`, pero no he conseguido que funcione, el código es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<body> 
<select name="comboseleccion">
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$query="SELECT * FROM municipios"
$resultado = mysqli_query($query);
if ($resultado)
while($renglon = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
$valor=$renglon['municipio'];
echo "<option value=".$valor.">".$valor."</option>\n";
}

?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

> Aclaro que la conexión esta correcta, ya la verifique.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con los errores que tengas. Explica porqué este código no te funciona y qué quieres hacer con este código. Saludos

Comment: `mysqli_query` espera como parámetro la conexión , y no le está pasando , posiblemente está recibiendo un error en el `HTML` y no se visualiza , intente con `mysqli_query($query,$con);` donde la variable `$con` debe contener la instancia de la clase conexión con un objeto que represente la conexión.

Comment: Puedes colocar el código de tu conexión para poderte escribir el código porque como bien dice Joel el problema debe de estar en que no estas pasando la conexión a mysqli_query que la requiere.

Comment: En esta pregunta puedes ver un [ejemplo minimo de como realizar una conexion a mysql con php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66424/me-faltan-2-par%C3%A1metros-en-mi-php/66426#66426)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, este es el codigo de la conexion:                      <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","vivienda");
?>                                                                                                                                   corregi la linea asi:  mysqli_query($query,$conexion); pero sigo sin lograr que funcione

Answer (score 1):

Me he permitido reproducir tu código sobre un valor hipotético, si estuvieses obteniendo datos de la BD y leyéndolos adecuadamente, se produciría en realidad un `select` con opciones.

Pero dicho `select` no sería conforme a la sintaxis, según la cual los `value` deben ir entre comillas. Esa, aunque en mi caso ambos `select`se muestran, puede ser causa de errores en algunos navegadores, o a la hora de recuperar el `value`en otro sitio.

---

**Reproducción del código**

### [DEMO](http://rextester.com/YPLI49908)

```
<?php

$resultado = 
array("1"=>"Municipio1", "2"=>"Municipio2", "3"=>"Municipio3");
$html_bien="VALUE CON COMILLA Y SIN NADA DESPUÉS DE <\option> \n";
$html_mal="LOS VALUE NO TIENEN COMILLAS\n";



    if ($resultado) 
    {

        $html_mal.="<select>";
        $html_bien.="<select>";


        foreach ($resultado as $k => $valor)
        {
            $html_bien.='<option value="'.$valor.'">'.$valor.'</option>';
            $html_mal.="<option value=".$valor.">".$valor."</option>\n";
        }
        $html_mal.="</select>";
        $html_bien.="</select>";

        echo $html_bien."\n\n";
        echo $html_mal;
    }
?>
```

---

**Resultado**

```
VALUE CON COMILLA Y SIN NADA DESPUÉS DE <\option>

  <select>
    <option value="Municipio1">Municipio1</option>
    <option value="Municipio2">Municipio2</option>
    <option value="Municipio3">Municipio3</option>
  </select> 


LOS VALUE NO TIENEN COMILLAS
  <select>
    <option value=Municipio1>Municipio1</option>
    <option value=Municipio2>Municipio2</option>
    <option value=Municipio3>Municipio3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Es una opción correcta mencionar lo de las comillas pero para este caso imprimir `HTML` **no** , en los dos casos imprime los `select` correctamente , como mencioné en los comentarios el error en que no se pasa la conexión a `mysqli_query` , sería bueno que pruebe su código en http://phpfiddle.org/